# Android quiz - increasing difficulty level of questions

Tags: java, android

I have an android app quiz which currently selects 10 random questions per game from a total of 500 questions. I would like the 10 questions to appear in order of difficulty e.g. question 1 is the easiest, gradually getting harder through to question 10 which is the hardest. Think of the gameplay in Who Wants to be a Millionaire for example.

The questions are stored as JSON in an external file. Each question has a difficulty level ("Level") from 1 to 10. Here is an example question:

```
{"itemId":"747AF1F8A59F7DD132CB08E","itemType":"BT_quizQuestion","Category":"Music","Level":3,"questionText":"Bruce Springsteen is also known as ...","correctAnswerText":"The Boss","incorrectText1":"Prince of Darkness","incorrectText2":"God of Thunder","incorrectText3":"Old Pete"},
```

My current code that selects the 10 questions at random is:

```
//randomize questions from pool then grab "x" number for quiz
    if(questionPool.size() > 0 && (quizRandomizeQuestions.equals("1") || quizRandomizeQuestions.toUpperCase().equals("YES")  )){
        Collections.shuffle(questionPool);
        childItems = new ArrayList<BT_item>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < questionPool.size(); i++){
            if(i < quizNumberOfQuestions){
                BT_item thisQuestion = questionPool.get(i);
                childItems.add(thisQuestion);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }//end for each
    }else{
        //showAlert("No Questions?", "This quiz does not have any questions associated with it?");
    }
```

I have established that I can add a question with difficulty level 1 (for instance) as follows:

```
String level = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(thisQuestion.getJsonObject(), "Level", "");
                    if(level.equals("1")) childItems.add(thisQuestion);
```

But how to add 1 question each of difficulty level 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 per game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through the question pool, it might be a better idea to loop through the questions you need:

```
for(int count=0;count<10;count++){
```

For each loop, find a question with the correct level:

```
    for(BT_item item:questionPool){ // loop through all the items in the question pool
        String level = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(item.getJsonObject(), "Level", "");
        if(level.equals(String.valueOf(count+1))) {
            childItems.add(item); // add 1 to count because it starts at 0, but levels start at 1
            break; // found a question, so break the inner loop (but not the outer one)
        }
    }
```

Then end the first loop:

```
}
```

Comment: Thanks kittycat, like your idea, testing this now.  Originally thisQuestion was defined as BT_item thisQuestion = questionPool.get(i); but this is no longer works with your new code. How and where should I redefine thisQuestion?

Comment: I converted the loop to an enhanced for loop explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Just use `item` instead of questionPool.get(i). I changed it because it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: You beauty it works. I just changed childItems.add(thisQuestion); to childItems.add(item);  Thank you so much kittycat.

Answer (score 0):

i'm trying to help you with some random code, but with the right idea (at least for me)

```
private static final int MAX_QUESTIONS = 10;
List<Question> questionsList = new ArrayList<Question>();

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_QUESTIONS; i++) {

    Question quest = new Question();
    quest.getQuestionFromJsonFileWithLevel(i+1);
    questionsList.add(quest);

}
```

Obviously you shoudl have a Question class wich represents you Question in the json file and with a method to get the questions from it

Now before start the game you'll have all the questions saved in the list, and no need to query them in the middle of the game

Comment: Thanks for your help Mat. I believe your solution is very similar to the accepted answer.